# Disable the option to edit SP document library in Desktop Word Application

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, document, office

I want to change my document libraries in SharePoint Online to allow staff to view, download and open in Word Desktop App, however I do not want them to be able to edit the document once it opens in the Word Desktop Application -- only to Save As another name on their PC.

I want to prevent them from altering the form in SP in any way.

What do I do?

Thanks,
Caulene

Answer (score 0):

You need to give your users Read-Only access and set the library to Open in Client Application.

Answer (score 0):

As josh said, you need to give your users Read-Only access to the document or the library.

You could follow the steps below to set the unique permission for your members.

Access the document library->Library settings ->Permissions for this document library ->Stop Inheriting Permissions->Set the users with Read permission.